# Difference Between Remove and Uninstall WindowsFeature

Tags: powershell, msmq, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am running Windows Server 2016, and added a Windows Feature via the Powershell command:

```
Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-MSMQ-Activation45
```

If I were to remove/uninstall it, which should I be using?

```
Remove-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-MSMQ-Activation45

Uninstall-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-MSMQ-Activation45
```

---

Also, will a server restart be required after the change?

Thank you.

Comment: possible-duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/650613/whats-the-difference-between-remove-windowsfeature-and-uninstall-windowsfeature

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/uninstall-windowsfeature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/uninstall-windowsfeature?view=winserver2012r2-ps):

> ### Uninstall-WindowsFeature
>
> Uninstalls specified Windows Server roles, role services, and features from a computer that is running Windows Server 2012 R2. By adding the Remove parameter, also deletes feature files, or payload, from a computer. ***This cmdlet replaces Remove-WindowsFeature***, the cmdlet that was used to uninstall roles, role services, and features in Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: #HOLD UP#
It's VERY IMPORTANT we all understand the differences here.
Remove-WindowsFeature is the **alias** for ServerManager, that still exists, and Uninstall-WindowsFeature is a cmdlet that **only** removes a role. Remove-WindowsFeature completely take the files out of WinSXS as well, as well as removing features that depend on those files **you did not specify**!!!